# how to turn on multiple buttons?

Tags: php, jquery

Got a bunch of letter buttons in code below:

```
<?php
    $a = range("A","Z");
?>

<table id="answerSection">
    <tr>

<?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach($a as $key => $val){
        if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
        echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\">";      
        if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now the code below is able to turn on an answer button:

```
$('#answer'+btn).addClass("answerBtnsOn");
```

Below is code for when "Add" button is clicked, it retrieves the "Answer" from the column:

```
 echo '<td class="answertd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchAnswer[$key]).'</td>';
echo "<td class='addtd'><button type='button' class='add' onclick=\"parent.addwindow('$searchAnswer[$key]');\">Add</button></td></tr>";
```

Below is the code where for each button (btn), it turns on/off the buttons:

```
function btnclick(btn)
{


    if ($(btn).hasClass("answerBtnsOn")) {
        $(btn).removeClass("answerBtnsOn").addClass("answerBtnsOff");
        return false;
    }

    if ($(btn).hasClass("answerBtnsOff")) {
        $(btn).removeClass("answerBtnsOff").addClass("answerBtnsOn");
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the only problem is that the code above is only able to turn on a single answer button on only. For example if the "Answer" is B, then it will turn answer button B on which is fine, or if the "Answer" is E, it is able to turn answer button E on.

The problem is that if there are multiple answers. If the "Answer" is B E, then it does not turn on buttons B and E, if "Answer" is A D F, it doesn't turn on buttons A D and F.

So my question is that how can I turn on multiple buttons if there are multiple Answers?

DEMO:

click [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text16.php) to view the demo and please follow the steps so you can use the demo:

- Step 1: When you open applicaton, you see a green plus button on the
  page, click on it and it will display a modal window.
- Step 2: In modal window there is a search bar, type in "AAA" and
  submit search, you will see a bunch of rows appear.
- Step 3: In the first row, you see under "Answer" colum that the
  answer is B, click on the "Add" button within this row, the modal
  window will close and you will see that the answer buttons have been
  displayed with the "B" button highlighted.

Now this works fine but it only works for single answer, follow the steps below:

- Step 4: Click on the green plus button again and perform the same
  search for "AAA";
- Step 5: This time select a row which has multiple answers under the
  "Answer" column e.g the third row has answer "A C" under the "Answer"
  column. Add this row by clicking on "Add" button
- Step 6: You will see that it displays the relevant buttons but it
  doesn't turn on any of the answer buttons, "A" button and "C" button
  are not highlighted green. This is the problem I am having

UPDATE:

```
//I can't use the toggle method you have mentioned because there is a suitable reason for this (long story)
    if ($(btn).hasClass("answerBtnsOn")) {
            $(btn).removeClass("answerBtnsOn").addClass("answerBtnsOff");
            return false;
        }

        if ($(btn).hasClass("answerBtnsOff")) {
            $(btn).removeClass("answerBtnsOff").addClass("answerBtnsOn");
            return false;
        }

//When "Add" button is clicked, it should turn on correct buttons
    function addwindow(condition) { 

    $('input[type=button]').each(function(){
        if (condition){
            $(this).addClass('correct');
        }
    });

    }
```

HTML code is same as html code on top of question

Comment: What is condition? you need to replace condition with the ACTUAL condition that returns tru if the answer is correct.

Comment: I tried correcting code to do this:   `$('#answer'+btn).each(function(){
        if ($('#answer'+btn).addClass('answerBtnsOn')){
            $(this).addClass('correct');
        }
    });` but it still only turns on button for single answer, not turning on buttons for multiple answers

Answer (score 1):

You need to use class instead of ID and give the same class to all correct answers, so all correct answers will get class of .correct and then in jquery:

```
$('.correct').addClass("answerBtnsOn");
```

**EDIT:**

Answering your question in the comment - yes, you should create an array of the buttons, run on it and add the `.correct` class to all the right answers.

Also change you code from:

```
if ($(btn).hasClass("answerBtnsOn")) {
        $(btn).removeClass("answerBtnsOn").addClass("answerBtnsOff");
        return false;
    }

    if ($(btn).hasClass("answerBtnsOff")) {
        $(btn).removeClass("answerBtnsOff").addClass("answerBtnsOn");
        return false;
    }
```

To:

```
$(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOn");
$(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOff");
```

It should do the same with much less code.

**EDIT2:**
The loop would be something like this:

```
$('input[type=button]').each(function(){
    if (condition){
        $(this).addClass('correct'));
    }
});
```

where condition is true if this answer is correct.

Comment: Hi, this code will turn on all answer buttons, i only want selected answer buttons to turn on

Comment: @user1490145 This is good solution. You only need to assign the `.correct` class in your `for` loop to all correct answers.

Comment: @Stano I am terrible with loops, can you show me what how to assign .correct class in for each loop so i know this for future?

Comment: @user1490145 post the code where you check if the answer is correct, so we can tell you what you need to change

Comment: @ftom2 I have updated code above, I have also provided a demo of the application itself so you can see what is currently happening. Just click on the url in the question and follow the steps

Comment: Do you think it is better creating an array of all of the answer buttons and then looping through them, picking out the correct answer buttons to turn on?

Comment: @ftom2 Is it ok if you show me how to store in a array of the buttons and loop through them? Im still learning arrays, for loops and while loops so be very helpful if I can see example of this in order to know how its written for future use?

Comment: Im guessing I can put your edit 2 straight into the addwindow() function?

Comment: put it where you want to check the correct answer and light up the buttons.

Comment: I have tried your code but it still turns on all the correct buttons. Let's start this again because I don't think we need to assign a class "correct" for all buttons and then pick out the correct ones. My old code was working when it comes to turning on a single button for a single answer. This is coz if "Answer" was "B", it looks for button "#answerB" and then turns it on. The reason it can't do multiple answers is coz if answer is "A E", it's trying to look for  "#answerAE" which is incorrect and why no buttons turn on, it shud b turn on "#answerA" and "#answerE". How to do this?

Comment: Dude, i feel like we got 10 steps back, I'm sorry but i really gave you all you need, just read the answers carefully and work with it, if you don't know loops you can't program, so i'll start there...

Comment: Im sorry about this, it is my fault, I should of explained it a lot more clearly, im sure there is a way of just using arrays and loops with the code I have got now and no need to add an extra class to all the buttons but I will try figure this out. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: There are a lot of ways but i offerred you one of the easiest ones. and don'y add the class to all the buttons, just the ones that are correct, i really don't know how to make it any clearer :(

Comment: ftom2 is right, simply don't test the "answerBtnsOff & answerBtnsOn" classes, use only single ".correct" class for testing the correctness of answer. Nothing more, nothing less. See [here](http://pastebin.com/i8Pmcf7u).

Comment: @ftom2 Can you show me how you would add the class to the correct answers because I think this is where I am messing up. I need `answerBtnsOff` and `answerBtnsOn` because the user is able to add or remove any answers if they wish by turning on or off the buttons. It seems like I need to modify a lot of the code to just include "correct" class

Comment: did u look at my answer? it has everything you need.

Comment: @ftom2 Yes I used your answer, but if I do not include "correct" class on all buttons and use your code, no buttons light up at all. if I put the correct class in all buttons, then all buttons light up, I must be putting you code in the wrong palce, At bottom of question I updated code so you can see how I used your function.

Comment: @user1490145 Take some paper and pencil and draw it as picture, if you cannot image. I also gave you functional script, as clean as possible. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Stano your code does not seem to work also, it seems a lot more complicated then it should be. All I want is after the "Add" button is clicked on, loop through all buttons and by using .answerBtnsOn, just turn on the buttons that match the answers. That is all I want. At moment it works only for single Answer, if Answer is "B", it will turn that "B" button on because it will look for "#answerB". But if there are multiple answers like "A E", it is looking for "#answerAE" which is incorrect, I want it to loop through the buttons and turn on button "#answerA" and "#answerE".

Comment: @user1490145 Thanks for explanation, now it's clear to me. I have updated the code again, now it works as you say. Also removed redundant onload from it. The corrected script is [here](http://pastebin.com/i8Pmcf7u). See also my answer below. I hope it will work for you finally. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code. At first we initialize php variables:

```php
$a = range("A","Z");
$correct = "ADERW"; // some string with correct letters (aka answers)
```

Now we place the javascript function into page's head (or to an external file):

```js
var oanswers = new Object(); // this object's attributes are named as correct letters
var answers = '<?php echo $correct; ?>'; //string
for (var i=0; i<answers.length; i++) {
  oanswers[answers[i]] = true;
}

function btnclick(btn) {
    if (!oanswers.hasOwnProperty(btn.id[6])) {
        return;
    }
    if ($(btn).hasClass('answerBtnsOff')) {
        $('.answers').each(function(){ // turn all correct answers on
            if (oanswers.hasOwnProperty(this.id[6])) {
                $(this).addClass('answerBtnsOn');
                $(this).removeClass('answerBtnsOff');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.answers').each(function(){ // turn all correct answers off again
            if (oanswers.hasOwnProperty(this.id[6])) {
                $(this).addClass('answerBtnsOff');
                $(this).removeClass('answerBtnsOn');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The btnclick function can toggle all correct answers Off and On. If you don't want toggling, simply erase the whole `else` branch. Instead of testing presence of the .created class, now it tests whether the object's property is defined or not.

Comment: where you put $correct = "ADERW"; , is that supposr to be changed to insert all letters e.g. $correct = "ABCD...";  or does it need to be blank?

Comment: This grid has exactly 5 correct answers A,D,E,R,W and 21 incorrect answers B,C,F,G,H,... etc.

Comment: How can it be made more dynamic, as that it could be 3 correct answers "A D F" or it could be 2 correct answers "G N" or it could be more or less answers?

Comment: @user1490145 Made it more dynamic. Do I understand it right, that those "correct answers" are obtained from php, or should be generated randomly in javascript?